# Cauchy principal value and displacing singularity

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration, residue-calculus

This question is related to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1927073/283676).

Let $x\in\mathbb{R}$, let $\alpha\in\mathbb{R}_{>0}$, and consider the integral
\begin{equation}
\int_{-\infty}^\infty\mathrm{d}y\,\frac{\exp(ixy)}{y^2-\alpha}.
\end{equation}
The integral as such diverges because of the simple poles on the real axis. In the actual phrasing of the question (this is homework) the teacher writes $\alpha^+:=\lim_{\epsilon\downarrow0}\alpha+i\delta$ instead of $\alpha$, seemingly suggesting that we should actually calculate the integral
\begin{equation}
\int_{-\infty}^\infty\mathrm{d}y\,\frac{\exp(ixy)}{y^2-(\alpha+i\delta)},
\end{equation}
where $\delta>0$, and then take the limit $\delta\downarrow0$. However that is not how the question is stated, and I remembered that even though the first integral is divergent, the Cauchy principal value of the integral
\begin{equation}
 \lim_{\delta\downarrow0}\left(\int_{-\infty}^{-\sqrt{\alpha}-\delta}\mathrm{d}y\,\frac{e^{ixy}}{y^2-\alpha}+\int_{-\sqrt{\alpha}+\delta}^{\sqrt{\alpha}-\delta}\mathrm{d}y\,\frac{e^{ixy}}{y^2-\alpha}+\int_{\sqrt{\alpha}+\delta}^\infty\mathrm{d}y\,\frac{e^{ixy}}{y^2-\alpha}\right)
\end{equation}
is well-defined, so I wanted to calculate this integral. Perhaps slightly naively I was expecting to get the same answer, and the comments around equation (7.39) in [this document](http://www.nhn.ou.edu/~milton/p5013/chap7.pdf) convinced me, but, when I do the actual calculation, I do not get the same answer. Of course my calculation can contain one or more errors but I feel like it is in order. Is it true that these ways of calculating are equivalent, and did I make a mistake, or are they actually different, and if so, how come? Any help is appreciated.

I should note that this is homework for a physics course.

**EDIT** To comment on user1952009's comments:

The actual integral we are calculating is
\begin{equation}
\int_{-\infty}^\infty\mathrm{d}q\,\frac{e^{\frac{ixq}{\hbar}}}{E^+-\frac{q^2}{m}},
\end{equation}
where $E^+:=\lim_{\epsilon\downarrow0}$. We have to show that it is equal to
\begin{equation}
-i\pi\sqrt{\frac{m}{E}}\exp\left(\frac{i|x|\sqrt{mE}}{\hbar}\right),
\end{equation}
so no, what you said is not what my teacher meant. What she means is calculating the integral
\begin{equation}
\int_{-\infty}^\infty\mathrm{d}q\,\frac{e^{\frac{ixq}{\hbar}}}{E+i\epsilon-\frac{q^2}{m}},
\end{equation}
and take the limit $\epsilon\downarrow0$, because this is the only wy to get the desired answer, and because one of the TA's the limit is there to shift the poles (even though that is not true because the limit just exists and is equal to $E$, so really one cannot show this is, because it is simply not true). Your comment is useful however because the PV I calculated using the definition I mentioned precisely gives me what would come out of the two integrals with the singularities shifted, as you said one can prove. What do you think? And how does one go about proving what you said?

Comment: Your teacher's approach is curious... I've learned to deal with poles on the real axis as shown in the first answer to the following question http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/564952/complex-integration-poles-real-axis

Comment: Yes I used the exact same way to avoid the poles but then you inevitably get a sine/cosine, while doing the approach with the singularities shifted just gets you the exponent.

Comment: it is not difficult to show that $p.v. \ 2\int_{-\infty}^\infty\,\frac{\exp(ixy)}{y^2-\alpha}\mathrm{d}y  = \lim_{ \epsilon \to 0} \int_{-\infty}^\infty\,\frac{\exp(ixy)}{y^2-\alpha+i\epsilon}\mathrm{d}y+\int_{-\infty}^\infty\,\frac{\exp(ixy)}{y^2-\alpha-i\epsilon}\mathrm{d}y$

Comment: @user1952009 How does that help?

Comment: this is what your teacher meant : compute the two integrals with $\alpha\pm i \epsilon$, take the mean, and let $\epsilon \to 0$

Comment: @user1952009 Believing your comment, that would mean that the PV of the integral is different from what they ask us to calculate (which would mean the question is slightly ill-defined).

Comment: @user1952009 I don't think so because the answer we are supposed to get is something with just an exponent (and some prefactors), and that is not what you get with the PV.

Comment: I don't see what you mean, and try what I said

Comment: if you had tried what I said, you would have seen the two integrals have the same limit as $\epsilon \to 0$, but showing the limit of their mean is equal to the $p.v.$ of the 1st integral is **easier** (and in general, it is always true that the $p.v.$ is equal to the limit of the mean of the integral slightly above and slightly below the singularity, but it is not always true that it is equal to the limit of only one, that's why I said what I said)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Cauchy Principal Value is given by

$$\begin{align}
\text{PV}\left(\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{\exp(ixy)}{y^2-\alpha}\,dy\right)&=\lim_{\delta\to 0^+}\left(\int_{-\infty}^{-\sqrt\alpha -\delta} \frac{e^{ixy}}{y^2-\alpha}\,dy+\int_{-\sqrt\alpha +\delta}^{\sqrt\alpha-\delta} \frac{e^{ixy}}{y^2-\alpha}\,dy+\int_{\sqrt\alpha +\delta}^\infty \frac{e^{ixy}}{y^2-\alpha}\right)
\end{align}$$

Using Cauchy's Integral Theorem, for $x>0$ this integral is given by

$$\begin{align}
\text{PV}\left(\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{\exp(ixy)}{y^2-\alpha}\,dy\right)&=\lim_{\delta\to0^+}\int_0^\pi \frac{e^{ix(-\sqrt\alpha +\delta e^{i\phi})}\,i\delta e^{i\phi}}{\delta e^{i\phi}(-2\sqrt\alpha +\delta e^{i\phi})}\,d\phi+\lim_{\delta\to0^+}\int_0^\pi \frac{e^{ix(-\sqrt\alpha +\delta e^{i\phi})}\,i\delta e^{i\phi}}{\delta e^{i\phi}(2\sqrt\alpha +\delta e^{i\phi})}\,d\phi\\\\
&=-\pi \frac{\sin(\sqrt \alpha x)}{\sqrt\alpha}
\end{align}$$

where neither pole is enclosed by the applicable contour.

Similarly for $x<0$, we have

$$\text{PV}\left(\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{\exp(ixy)}{y^2-\alpha}\,dy\right)=\pi \frac{\sin(\sqrt \alpha x)}{\sqrt\alpha}
$$

> Note that this Cauchy Principal Value integral differs conceptually from the function $F(x,\alpha)$ as given by
>
> $$\begin{align}
> F(x,\alpha)&=\lim_{\epsilon\to 0^+}\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{e^{ixy}}{y^2-(\alpha +i\epsilon)}\tag 1
> \end{align}$$

In $(1)$, the poles are in the first and third quadrants.  Therefore, only one, but not both of the poles is enclosed in a contour in the upper-half plane or the lower half-plane.  Then, applying the Residue Theorem in the case for which $x>0$, we obtain

$$F(x,\alpha)=i\pi \frac{e^{i\sqrt\alpha x}}{\sqrt \alpha}$$

while in the case for which $x<0$, we obtain

$$F(x,\alpha)=-i\pi \frac{e^{-i\sqrt\alpha x}}{\sqrt \alpha}$$

Comment: Well, yes, thanks, that is what I got, so the question as stated is simply wrong.

Comment: You're welcome.  My pleasure.   I'm not sure as to your concern/issue then.  The physics of the problem should dictate which of these integrals is applicable.

Comment: Thanks. The issue was that the question asked us to prove that $F(x,\alpha)=PV(\ldots)$, which is not true.